# read , remove and add element to linkedlist from different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, thread-safety, linked-list

**What would be the best programming practice for this case:**

I have a linkedlist with file-objects, once in a while incoming file objects are added to this list (*AddThread*). 

These file-objects need to be "processed", supposedly by another thread (*ProcessThread*). So whenever file-objects are added to the list, they need to be processed one at a time, while other file-objects still can be added to the list. 
 During processing, an item from the list is read and afterwards removed from that list. Processing stops whenever the list is empty, and starts again if new items are added.

**How I see it:**

Whenever a change is applied to the list (item added), a change event is fired. This event wakes up the *ProcessThread*. The *ProcessThreads* locks the list for a small amount of time to read it and releases the lock again. When the file-object is processed it locks it again to quickly remove the item from the list and unlocks it. 
When there are no file-objects anymore in the list, the *ProcessThread* is set to sleep.

Is this the right way to do it, or are there other better options..?

Greets Daan

**Edit**: I use a linkedlist, because then I can add a file-object on the beginning or the end of the list, so that it is processed before/after others. Processing can take up to a minute, depending on the networkload. Sometimes it will fail, and it needs to be processed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after reading the other posts and updates, how about two 'plain' queues, (low and high priority), a mutex/CS lock and a semaphore, making up a priority blocking queue?  To add a file-object, acquire the lock, push the file-object onto one of the queues, release the lock, signal the semaphore.  In the process-thread/s, wait on the semaphore, acquire the lock, TryTake from the high-priority queue and, if this fails, Take from the low-priority queue, then release the lock and process the file-object.

Comment: Looks great, thank you very much, going to try that. I just have one question: what is a CS lock?

Comment: Oh - if a file-object fails, you can reset it, inc some internal 'retry count' and add it back on to one of the queues just like a new file-object. A process-thread will then get it and retry.  Maybe, after some retry limit is reached, you could queue it off to some logger thread.

Comment: 'Critical Section', (Windows term, sorry), - it's a 'lock' statement in C#.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to use the BlockingCollection.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

*If you take an element from the queue and the queue is empty the thread will block until there is something in the queue.

*If you add an element to the queue and the queue is full the thread will block until there is space.

*It is thread safe.

Comment: Looks very interesting, but I don't think it's possible to use this in combination with a linkedlist. I need to be able to put at an item on top or at the end of a list ..See the edit in my question.

Comment: If it fails you could use the same thread to rerun it again. You don't need to put it back in the queue. Another option would be to use 2 BlockingCollections. One regular and one priority. Than each thread that consumes will first look into the priority and try to grab an element. If it is empty it will continue with the regular queue.

Comment: 'Another option would be to use 2 BlockingCollections. One regular and one priority.' Hmm. not sure this works. Consumer threads would get stuck on an empty low-priority collection and would be unaware of a new item added to the high-priority collection.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using .net 4.0 I would consider the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) container.

This gives you thread safe access to either end of a queue of objects, you wouldn't need to worry yourself about the implementation of the locking mechanism.

As far as firing up the process thread, I would look on this as a separate issue. An event sounds like the right way to go based on your description but whether a polling or event driven solution is most appropriate depends on how often the queue is likely to be activated, how fast the process is, how responsive you need the system to be.

One other thing.  Why don't you just remove the file-object from the list when you begin processing?  Is there a chance the processing may fail and you'll need to try again?  If you leave the item in the list is there a chance you might run 2 processing threads and process it twice?  It's impossible to say based on the description but worth considering.

Comment: I don't think I can use a queue because some file-objects have a higher priority than others. See my edits.